# Function CudnnConvolutionBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 - got [294, 592, 1, 1] but expected shape compatible with [294, 768, 1, 1]

Tags: pytorch

I'm working on a pytorch (torch=1.2.0) project considering CNN's pruning. I dropped few filters from a model and tried to retrain the reduced model. However my code crashes while processing backward pass.
My final layer was [294, 768, 1, 1], but was reduced to [294, 592, 1, 1]. This means in the layer before the final one the amount of filters was reduced from 768 to 592. The forward pass runs well, meaning all the model layers are compatible, but it crashed immediately on the last layers backprop with the following message:

Function CudnnConvolutionBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 - got [294, 592, 1, 1] but expected shape compatible with [294, 768, 1, 1]

I don't understand it, as the model was pruned, but it looks like it tries to "backprop" on the original layer dimensions.

Comment: Can you provide the content of `CudnnConvolutionBackward `?

Comment: CudnnConvolutionBackward  is a pytorch inner function used by backward()

Comment: You need to provide some code, without it we have absolutely no way of helping you.